# How to run app.js deployed on remote server from local bash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, ssh

I deployed my web app on GoDaddy. My web app is developed in Node.js. So, I need to run app.js. I can run app.js from my computer's bash command prompt. But if I shut down my laptop, then I can't see the web page, i.e. the app.js is down. How can I run app.js so that I don't need to worry about shutting down my laptop?

Comment: Can you explain better what you actually have deployed where?  Do you have a virtual server? How are you running your node process?  etc?

Comment: Can you install tmux on your webserver?  I have used it for a similar task.

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the response. So, I uploaded the web app on GoDaddy account (I'm not admin though) using WinScp client. Then, I ran the app by the command on bash: node app.js . If I shut down the laptop, the app.js goes down (i.e. I can't see the pages in the browser: like [link]http://ipadress:portno/abc.html). How can I up the app.js so that I can shut down my laptop, but still the app will run on remote server(in my case GoDaddy). I don't have virtual server. Thanks.

Comment: @ppovoski, will the tmux run the app on remote server if I shut down my pc?

Comment: Yes, it creates a session that is stored on the server.  You can create a named session and detach/attach to that session at any time.  If the server is restarted, it will destroy the session and kill the process. However, if you are unable to install it on the remote server, then it is not an option.  It may be installed already, or a similar app called 'screen'.  In your shell type, `which tmux` or `which screen` to see if either are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you're literally logged in to the server as a user of some kind, and in that terminal session you run something like `node ./app.js` to run your app, then when  your session closes the app will also shut down, since you're running it as a user which then logs out (similar to how Word doesn't keep running a spell check when you hit spell check and then power down your machine).

What you need to do is configure your application to run as a service.  The specific mechanism to do this will depend greatly on what kind of server you're running (Ubuntu, Centos, Windows, etc).

Most modern Linux distros come with systemd, for example, and that would be how I'd do it on them.  There's a good tutorial on it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-node-js-applications-using-systemd-and-nginx).